# sample with row specific probability in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I'm trying to sample a dummy based on probabilities that are part of my data.table. If my data.table only has two rows, this works:

```
library(data.table)
playdata <- data.table(id = c("a","b"), probabilities = c(0.2, 0.3))
playdata[, sampled_dummy := sample(c(0,1),1, prob = probabilities)]
```

if it has three or more rows, it does not:

```
library(data.table)
playdata <- data.table(id = c("a","b","c"), probabilities = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
playdata[, sampled_dummy := sample(c(0,1),1, prob = probabilities)]

Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

Can someone explain this? I know I can apply any function row by row by force but why does sample break the standard data.table syntax? Should it not do everything row by row anyways?

edit: a usual workaround throws the same error:

```
playdata[, sampled_dummy := sample(c(0,1),1, prob = probabilities), by = seq_len(nrow(playdata))]
```

Comment: You are sampling from two values `c(0,1)` but are supplying three probabilities `c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)`. I'm not sure exactly what behavior you are expecting here. Are you trying to specify the probability for just the 0 value? R rarely evaluates expressions row-by-row by default since that's inefficient. It will try to operate on the columns of the data all at once.

Comment: In the first row, I want to draw a 0 with probability 0.2 (hence a 1 with probability 0.8), in the second row I want to draw a 0 with probability 0.3 (hence a 1 with probability 0.7)...

Comment: That's not how the sample command works. If you do `sample(c(0,1),1, prob = c(0.2, 0.3))` It will normalize the probabilities to sum to 1. So it will draw values from a distribution where 0 has probability .4 and 1 has probability .6.  Same as `sample(c(0,1),1, prob = c(2, 3))`. And then since you only return 1 value, it will get recycled to the full length of the column.

Comment: thanks! Thats another issue of my code. But even if that is solved, one still has to do some sapply loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do the sampling row-wise, so I'll demo with `sapply`:

```r
set.seed(42)
playdata[, sampled_dummy := sapply(probabilities, function(prob) sample(0:1, size=1, prob=c(prob,1-prob)))]
#        id probabilities sampled_dummy
#    <char>         <num>         <int>
# 1:      a           0.2             0
# 2:      b           0.3             0
# 3:      c           0.4             1
```

Though I suspect that it might be easier for you to use `runif(.N) > probabilites`?

```r
playdata[, sampled_dummy := +(runif(.N) >= probabilities)]
#        id probabilities sampled_dummy
#    <char>         <num>         <int>
# 1:      a           0.2             1
# 2:      b           0.3             1
# 3:      c           0.4             0
```

Comment: thanks, this solves everything at once. My question was mixing two issues: A mistake in sample() and why do we need to sapply sample (but not other functions). Why does this not work:

playdata[, otherprob := 1 - probabilities]

playdata[, sampled_dummy := sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = c(probabilities, 1-otherprob))]

Comment: `length(prob)` must equal `length(x)` in the call to `sample`, but without `sapply` the length of `prob` is `.N`